# Windows 2008 VPN Connection

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I have a Windows 2008 Server that I was looking into connecting to a secure VPN. However the server is public facing and hosts a website. If I have this server connect to the secured VPN will this server be public facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will remain public facing if your VPN service provider has "split Tunneling" functionality which actually split the VPN tunnel for your specified applications. It will allow you to direct some traffic or applications through a VPN tunnel while sending other traffic directly through a local network's default gateway.

Hope this answers your question or for more info please read 3rd screenshot on this http://www.purevpn.com/purevpn-dialer/

Answer (score 1):

It depends largely on what your definition of "Secure VPN" is, how said VPN is configured, and what's on the other side of that VPN.

Some VPN configurations force all traffic through the tunnel. In this case, then no, your website will no longer be accessible except through the VPN.

If, on the other hand, your VPN implements split tunnelling, then yes, it's most likely that your website will remain available to the public internet and only specific subnets will be routed over the VPN tunnel.